Call a function from another script
I am trying to develop an Excel addin that would use Three.js.
For that, I have several files :

Home.html, my main html
3dModel.js, the script using three to create and display my 3d model
Home.js, my main Excel addin script

Everything is working in both js scripts on their own, but I would like to call a function funct1(), defined in 3dModel.js inside Home.js.
Is this possible ?
I have tried :
// 3dModel.js
export funct1(){
    console.log("test");
}

// Home.js
import { funct1 } from './3dModel.js';
funct1();


But I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" whereas I am calling both my scripts as modules :
<script type="module" src="./3dModel.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./Home.js"></script>

What am I missing ? Thanks a lot for your help, I am still a beginner !

You are using ES6 syntax(import) over CommonJS(require) syntax. In order to resolve your issue try using require instead of import.
In your 3D model javascript file:
var funct1 = function(value) {
  console.log("test");
};

module.exports.funct1 = funct1;

In you other file use require:
var 3dModel = require('./3dModel');
3dModel.funct1()


Thanks for the details !
Unfortunately, I have tried and I get : "ReferenceError: require is not defined"...

instead of use import, use require module
